# How to use nodejs to parse excel that has even complicated formula inside?

Tags: node.js, excel, vba

I have a .xlsx file. In it I have some formulas like:

`=A5*A7`

or even very complicated ones:

`=IF(B14<B$4, B14*C$3, IF(B14<B$5, (B14-B$4)*C$4+B$4*C$3, IF(B14<B$6, (B14-B$5)*C$5+(B$5-B$4)*C$4+B$4*C$3, IF(B14<B$7, (B14-B$6)*C$6+(B$6-B$5)*C$5+(B$5-B$4)*C$4+B$4*C$3,(B14-B$7)*C$7+(B$7-B$6)*C$6+(B$6-B$5)*C$5+(B$5-B$4)*C$4+B$4*C$3))))`

Even sometimes I need to parse those with VBA functions, like:

`=MyCustomizedFunction(A1)`

Is there any good suggestion?

Thanks,

Comment: Could you explain a little more about what your desired output is?  I'm not sure I follow your goal.

Comment: I just hope to get data in object. Not very specific needs. Even a matrix-like array is ok, for example: `[[c1r1], [c2r1], [c1r2], [c2r2]]`